# carouFredSel works locally but not with MAMP or a live server

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I'm having some trouble with the carouFredSel jQUERY plugin. I got everything styled and working nicely locally (without MAMP), but when I move the files to my live server and made sure everything was in the right place it just broke.

I can the same file locally, and the carousel works. I'm starting to think it has something to do with my code, or how I laid it out. I'm not very well versed in Javascript (I can *use* jQUERY), so this is kind of a learning process for me. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my header code, I'm using the HTML 5 Boilerplate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <!-- LOAD JQUERY -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- GOOGLE WEB FONTS -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,700,600,300,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

            <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carousel.css" />

    <!-- MODERNIZER -->
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <!-- CAROUSEL & jQUERY UI -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>

            <!-- CAROUSEL -->
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.1.0.js"></script>

            <!-- optional include helper plugins -->
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                    auto: true,
                    prev: '#prev2',
                    next: '#next2',
                    pagination: {
                        container: ".pager",
                        pagination: {anchorBuilder: function(nr) { return '<a href="#"><span>'+'XXX'+nr+'</span></a>'; }}
                    },
                    width: 700,
                    height: 150,
                    align: 'center',
                    scroll: {
                items: 4,
                fx: "scroll",
                easing: "swing",
                duration: 1000,
                pauseOnHover: true
                        },
                });
            });
            </script>

</head>
```

**EDIT:** My mistake, I totally forgot to post what my Error console said. It says as follows:

Error: TypeError: $("#carousel").carouFredSel is not a function.

Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We'll need more information than "it just broke"! What error messages, if any, are you getting? What is it not doing that you are expecting it to do? What is is doing that you are not expecting it to do? Also use a tool like Firebug to make sure all your scripts and other files are being loaded

Comment: My mistake, I totally forgot to post what my terminal said.

Comment: You may be able to edit your question to ad the extra info

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I'm not quite sure what I did wrong though. Here's what I've replaced the above with:

```
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know why that worked? Possibly because jQUERY was initialized twice somewhere?